# nodejs http.getagent on v0.10.6 can't work

Tags: node.js

I'm a newbie to nodejs ,recently i tried  upgrade nodejs  from 0.4.7 to 0.10.6,but my app.js got a error message ,

"http.getAgent: TypeError: Object# has no method 'getAgent' "

then checked codes from app.js found

" var somevar = http.getAgent('somedomain' , 80 ); "

so which class or method can replace getAgent  with 0.10.6 ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: From some [very old docs](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.7/api/http.html#http.getAgent) it seems like you probably don't even really need the HTTP Agent.  What do you end up doing with `somevar`?

Comment: There might some info in the upgrade docs in node wiki.

Answer (score 0):

I actually can't find any information on the removal of `getAgent` -- [even in the changelog](http://nodejs.org/changelog.html).  It seems that you would only need to use the `http` agent for hyper-technical reasons.  If you really need to use the agent, it seems that you can use `http.globalAgent` (property, not function) instead.